# Show the positive, non-empty set of real numbers $F$ is countable.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing

It is true that for every non-empty finite $A \in F$.

$$
\sum_{x \in A} \leq 1
$$

By the Archimedean Property we have $x>0, \exists n \in \mathbb{N} : \frac{1}{n} < x$. Let $S = \{x \in F: x > \frac{1}{n}\}$. We know then that $S$ must contain all of $F$ and that we can count $S$ with $f(n) = \frac{1}{n}$. Therefore $F$ must be countable.

I feel close but believe I am missing some rigor.

Comment: Hint: What is the definition of countability? (Bijection. Your arguments head in the direction of "at least countable")

Comment: That there is a function mapping it to the naturals. I thought I covered that in my $f(n)$?

Comment: You still have to injectively map the (positive) reals onto $\mathbb{N}$ which is not possible.

Comment: A friend of mine gave me a hint about using the cardinality of the set - showing there was an upper bound..

Comment: this is equivalent^^ find a bijection (or better show that there cannot be one) see https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Real_Numbers_are_Uncountable for instance :)

Comment: @ Max "into" not "onto"

Comment: $F$ is some subset of positive reals, such that every finite subset $A \subseteq F$ sums to at most $1$ ? I can't even tell what's given, and what's to be proved.

Comment: We can not prove that $F$ is (infinite) countable. The best we can prove is that $F$ is *at most* countable. It is obvious that $F$ may be finite.  For instance,  take $F=\{0.25, 0.05\}$. Any subset of $F$ sums to $\leq 1$.

Comment: I think the intention is to show that $F$ is at most countable yes.

Comment: Let us prove that $F$ is at most countable. For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $n>0$, let $S_n = \{x \in F: x > \frac{1}{n}\}$. It is easy to see that $F=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty S_n$.  Suppose $F$ is uncountable.  Since  $F$ is the a countable union of $S_n$, we have that there must be $n_0$ such that $S_{n_0}$ is uncountable.  So, take $A$ to be a subset of $S_{n_0}$ such that $A$ has $2n_0$ elements.  Then $A$ is  a finite subset of $F$ and $$ \sum_{x \in A} x \geq 2$$ Contradiction. So $F$ must be at most countable.

Comment: Here is another way to prove that $F$ is at most countable. For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $n>0$, let $S_n = \{x \in F: x > \frac{1}{n}\}$. Suppose for some $n_0$, $S_{n_0}$ has $n_0$ or more elements, take $A$ to be a subset of  $S_{n_0}$ such that $A$ has $n_0$ elements. Then $A$ is  a finite subset of $F$ and $$ \sum_{x \in A}x > 1$$ 
Contradicition. So, for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $n>0$, $S_n$ has less than $n$ elements. On the other hand, it is easy to see that $F=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty S_n$. So $F$ is the a countable union of finite sets. So $F$ is at most countable.

Comment: @Ramiro Your last proof makes perfect sense to me. Thanks!